# "Debug Assertion Failed" Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

There seems to be an error with my piece of code in c.
when I try to run it, it gives the "Microsoft visual Studio C++ Runtime Library".
it gives this error after I give the first input and press enter.
In my code, I'm trying to get some information from the user and then printing it in a new format.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int     Code;
int     Day, Month, Year;
float   Price;

printf("Enter Item Number: ");
scanf_s("%d", &Code);

printf("Enter Unit Price: ");
scanf_s("%7.2f", &Price);

printf("Enter Purchase Date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
scanf_s("%2.2d/%2.2d/%4.4d", &Month, &Day, &Year);

/* Here is the New Format Printout */

printf("Item\tUnit\tPurchase\n\tPrice\tDate\n");
printf("%3.3d\t$%f\t%d/%d/%d", Code, Price, Month, Day, Year);
return 0;
}
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb8Og.jpg)

Comment: Read scanf documentation again. Your formats are wrong.

Comment: `%7.2f` --> `%2f`, `%2.2d` --> `%02d`

Comment: You should already get a bunch of compiler warnings like `'scanf_s' : unknown type field character '.' in format specifier` or `'scanf_s' : too many arguments passed for format string`. Please don't ignore them

Comment: There isn't any sort of error after building the code.

Comment: You tagged this as `C++`.  Why aren't you using `cin`?  Using `scanf_s` or similar functions removes the type-safety features of `cin`.  If you get the format specification incorrect for `scanf_s`, the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: `scanf_s("%2.2d/%2.2d/%4.4d", &Month, &Day, &Year);`  --  Also, a format string with the `/` character in it does not give you masked editing features, if that is what you were trying to accomplish with that string.  I wish it were that simple.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with this code is that inside the scanf of the "Unit Price", instead of just writing "%f", it has written "%7.2f".
any sort of formatting whatsoever should be done in the printf part and in can not be defined in the scanf.